# JQuery $.get wont work, even console.log() no errors

Tags: jquery, get

I am working now with jQuery, now when I do a $.get(); request it will not work, I have trying to debug but I don`t get any message. Also I get no errors in the console.

**jQuery:**

```
$('.loginForm').hide( 'slide', {direction:'right'}, 1000);
console.log('Starting...');
$.get('./login.php?user' + value1 + '&pass=' + value2, function(data) {
    console.log('try =>' + data);
    if(data.status == 'ok') {
        $.get('./userdata.php', function(data) {
            console.log('userdata =>' + data);
            if(typeof data.message == 'string') {
                $('.form-control.password').css('border', '2px solid #a94442');
                $('.form-control.password').css('-webkit-box-shadow', 'inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075)');
                $('.form-control.password').css('box-shadow', 'inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075)');
                $('.loginForm').show('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 1000);
            } else {
                $('.loginForm').html('hi');
                $('.loginForm').show('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 1000);
            }
        });
    } else {
        $('.form-control.password').css('border', '2px solid #a94442');
        $('.form-control.password').css('-webkit-box-shadow', 'inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075)');
        $('.form-control.password').css('box-shadow', 'inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075)');
        $('.loginForm').show('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 1000);
    }
});
console.log('Done!');
```

When I run this script the console says 'Starting...' and 'Done!' But no informtion about console.log('try =>' + data); or console.log('userdata =>' + data);

Why? How to fix this?

Comment: I am guessing it is not able to resolve the URL, and it's error out. Most probably 404. Put a debug point on the web server and check if it is even calling the web server method.

Comment: `console.log('Done!');` is outside from the callback function => will ever be printed

Comment: I was forgotten an = on $.get(); Thanks Yogesh!

Comment: I also see another potential error in your code with '?user'+value. Seems like you forgot an "="